# Dynamic multicast in AWS not working using IGMPv2

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat8, multicast

I have a java application running on tomcat on multiple ec2 instances, and I want to deploy it in cluster mode which is working when I configure in each tomcat server a `StaticMembershipInterceptor` for the other instances. But this is not a viable solution since I want to use auto scaling, and I don't want to modify each time the `server.xml`

So I try to use `McastService` on ip address `224.0.0.4` to run a multicast address, and have the same configuration on all instances, I also configured on my VPC the following

- a transit Gateway with the attribute Multicast support Enabled
- a transit gateway attachement linked to my VPC and my 2 private subnets
- a transit gateway multicast domain with IGMPv2 support enabled, and associated to my subnets using the TG attachement
- on the security group of my instances I've enabled all traffic between the local network

on my ec2 instances I disabled the check source/Dest and forced IGMP to version 2, but I still can't get multicasting working, I try to ping the multicast address but all packets are lost.

Is there another configuration I'm missing ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the part where my instances should be nitro to allow this, I switched from t2.micro to t3.micro and it worked